# How can I test this method with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

```
import { format, getDaysInMonth, getMonth, getYear, isValid, parse } from "date-fns";

export class DateService {

  public getDaysInMonth(month?: Date) {
    return getDaysInMonth(month || new Date());
  }
```

How do I test it? How can I access the function implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import the class:

```
import { DateService } from "./DateService";
```

setup your describe block and instantiate the DateService

```
describe("DateService", () => {
  const dateService = new DateService();
```

And then test results:

```
 it("should return the number of days", () => {
  const month = new Date(2022, 4); // May 2022
  const daysInMonth = dateService.getDaysInMonth(month);
  expect(daysInMonth).toBe(31);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jest
  .useFakeTimers()
  .setSystemTime(new Date('2020-01-01'));

describe("DateService", () => {
  test("getDaysInmonth", () => {
    // arrange
    const dateService = new DateService();
    const expected = new Date('2020-01-01');

    // act
    const actual = dateService.getDaysInMonth();
    
    // assert
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  }
})
```